# Nativescript Vue Actionbar Duplicated Android

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using Nativescript-Vue and can't figure out how to remove the ActionBar that appears by default in Android with the application name (in iOS it does not appear). Any ideas?

If I add a new `<ActionBar />` in the template it shows below the "default" ActionBar that I am not able to get rid of.

If I use actionBarHidden="true" in my `<Page />` tag, I can't add my custom ActionBar.

The project was built using `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>`, it has basically the same configuration (manifest.xml and other App_Resources) that this example has: https://github.com/tralves/groceries-ns-vue/tree/master/app/App_Resources

I am using multiple frames like this, maybe that has something to do with the issue:

```
<Page>
 <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal" @selectedIndexChange="showComponent">
  <TabViewItem title="Servicios" iconSource="res://ic_person_outline_18pt">
    <Frame id="services">
      <Categories />
    </Frame>
  </TabViewItem>

  <TabViewItem title="Citas" iconSource="res://ic_date_range_18pt">
    <Frame id="bookings">
      <Bookings v-if="show_bookings" />
    </Frame>
  </TabViewItem>

  <TabViewItem title="Carrito" iconSource="res://ic_shopping_basket_18pt">
    <Frame id="cart">
      <Cart v-if="show_cart" />
    </Frame>
  </TabViewItem>
 </TabView>
</Page>
```

In each component (Categories, Bookings, Cart) I am rendering the specific ActionBar.

This image shows the problem, the app name is Ameiz:

[Double ActionBar Issue - Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUD38.png)

Thanks.-

Comment: You may directly set a title to your ActionBar or when you place a custom title view the default with app name will go away. If you are using multiple frames, make sure you hide one in the right frame.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, I tried directly setting a title but the default ActionBar with the app name remains. Maybe it has something to do with the multiple frames, though I don't know what might be the problem since I am only rendering the content in the frame once the user clicks the TabViewItem. I'll edit my question with more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Page will have it's own Actionbar. As Page is the parent for TabView and each tab has it's own Frame & Page, you get 2 ActionBar there.

Set `actionBarHidden="true"` on the parent Page of TabView. If you still face issues, please share a Playground example where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for this! I put this in my tab routing component by injecting Page into my constructor!

Comment: Hi @Petey, I am having a similar issue although I am not using multiple frames. I have my ActionBar declared in my own component and then include it inside the content of a RadSideDrawer. Unfortunately I get duplicated ActionBars and if I add the `actionBarHidden="true"` it hides my custom ActionBar I declared. Could you please explain how you achieved your fix? I'm still a little new when it comes to both NativeScript and Vue.